# Difference between json and JSON (application/json) on Postman

Tags: json, postman

question of a beginner here. I see on some videos/tutorials, when they use Postman, they select Body:raw and JSON like this on the image.

[image]

But when I open Postman and want to select the same, there is only this JSON like this on this image.

[image]

Is there any difference?  On the headers I have this selection:
[image]

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the answer by myself. The JSON(application/json) with the orange text is from the google chrome extension of Postman which is obsolete.